# Rust - move value in hashmap without cloning and keep value in hashmap

Tags: rust, hashmap, unsafe, ownership

I'm using a hashmap as an environment for a tree walk interpreter. This hashmap maps strings to values. Value is an enum that implements the Clone trait but not Copy. The following is a huge performance bottleneck when values bound to certain variables are very large:

```
enum Term {
    ...
    Var(String) 
}

fn eval(t: &Term, env: &mut HashMap<String, Value>) -> Result<Value, MyError> {
   match t {
       Term::Var(name) => {
           env.get(name)
           .map(|v| (*v).clone())
           .unwrap_or(Err(MyError { ..., msg: format!("Unexpected Variable {}", name) }))
       }
       ...
   }

}
```

`v` can be very large (for example a list of 10k elements), so cloning can become a huge issue for performance. What I'd like is for an owned version of `v` to be returned by `get`. `remove` does this, but the issue is that the data needs to persist in the hash map. Is there any way to effectively do this, either with a HashMap or a custom data structure?

It seems like this will require unsafe code, but I don't know anything about unsafe as I haven't touched it.

Comment: Why do you need an owned version of `v` returned? If its just to avoid a lifetime bound, then you can use shared ownership via `Rc`/`Arc`. If you need to do stuff with `v` that *requires* a transfer of ownership, then you can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: Wouldn’t that require returning and Option<&Value>? I’m not sure that’s possible because I would be returning a reference to a local variable.

Comment: It's not a local variable, it's owned by the HashMap.

Comment: In this case yes, but there are other cases of eval where new variants of value are created and returned.

Comment: Could [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) be of use? Its a type that can hold either a reference or owned value.

Comment: I’m not familiar with cow but in order to construct a Cow from a reference, would I have to clone? Also, would I need to update the entire function to return a cow? Im not familiar with smart pointers at all.